# How does maven-assembly-plugin filter out whole directories?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

My distribution file is like below. I want create a `public` and `logs` folder under my project root folder (${basedir}) and package them to a zip file. Now, my problem is that all files (for example, 1.log, 2.log) under `public` and `logs` folders **are not packaged** into zip file, but all directories under `public` and `logs` folders **are packaged** into the zip file.

How to filter out the directories too? I just want to create a **empty** pubic and logs folder in my zip file.

```
   <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}\src\main\bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>\bin</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.sh</include>
                <include>*.bat</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}\logs</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <outputDirectory>\logs</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}\public\</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <outputDirectory>\public</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you provided:

```
<exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
```

will only match files in the directory that have format X.Y.  That is, each one must include a '.' and have an extension.  Presumably the subdirectories do not have this format.  So, add another  line to each  section:

```
<exclude>**/*</exclude>
```

I think that will do it.  The [Ant directory task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html) includes some helpful examples.